# Jquery Asp.Net GridView Data Binding

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview

**How to call Method Jquery ?**

```
public void GetGrid()
        {
            DataProviderDataContext db = new DataProviderDataContext();
            GridView1.DataSource = db.Employees.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

**I do not know English pls help**

Comment: What are you trying to do with jQuery?

Comment: the code behind that method call with Jquery, Gridview Data binding

Answer (score 0):

**This is Calling Page Method into Jquery Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   beforeSend:function(xhr),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url:"your page name"/"method name",
   data:"{}",
   dataType: "text",
   success: function(response) { //do something; },
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, text, error){}
});
```